# How to activate automatic Whatsapp template from Facebook business manager?

Tags: java, node.js, facebook, whatsapp, apex

I'm setting up a new connection between whatsapp and zendesk to support better Cust.service experience. The actual goal is to be able to sendout automated response through whatsapp that is triggered from salesforce, but I'm quite new to this and have limited knowledge about whatsapp API.

In our facebook business manager, I have created the Account API WhatsApp Business and also connected the phone number to the API whatsapp business, but the next step is confusing me, which I need to register the app using /v1/account node account. I dont understand this part.

further step is "Request a Registration Code"
Send the telephone number and vname certificate string encoded in your base64 to request the registration code. You can request to receive your code via SMS or voice call.

Use endpoint / v1 / account to request your registration code.

POST /v1/account

{
    "cc": "your-country-code",
    "phone_number": "your- phone-number-without-country-code",
    "method": "sms" | "voice",
    "cert": "your-verified-name-cert-in-base64",
    "pin": "your-existing-6-digit-pin" # required if two-factor verification is enabled
}

I expect to have whatsapp template that can be used by our registered phone number and set up auto response, then later we can create trigger in salesforce using something (which I still dont know)

Answer (score 0):

You also to need to share what kind of setup you're using for the WhatsApp Business API for us to help answer this question. 
It seems you're on the technical steps at this point from their documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started

1. You should first complete the setup (either on-premise or AWS setup) before moving to the registration step. If you have setup the containers locally, the docs recommend the Postman collection to start sending requests to the WhatsApp Business API container endpoints. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/postman
2. Once you've completed the first step, you'll have a way to make API requests to the WhatsApp Business API web endpoint.
3. The registration step after that should be straightforward. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/account